# App Crashes While Trasitioning One Fragment To Another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to jump from one fragment to another fragment. But whenever i click the button to jump on second fragment my app crashes.
Here are my source files. Please help !
I want to Navigate Tab1 to AlertScreen.
Here is Tab1.java

```
package com.example.bavarian.sos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;




public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    ImageButton HelpButton ;
    private boolean playing = false;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        HelpButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        final MediaPlayer Alarm = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.sound);
        //private boolean playing = false ;
        HelpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new AlertScreen();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }

        });

        return rootView ;
    }
}
```

AlertScreen.java

```
package com.example.bavarian.sos;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AlertScreen extends Fragment {
public AlertScreen(){

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_screen,container,false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

alert_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Alerrt Screen"
    android:id="@+id/alerttext"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="176dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

What i am missing here ???

Comment: What does the logcat say/

Comment: Replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Logcat :  No view found for id 0x7f0d0076 (com.example.bavarian.sos:id/fragment_container) for fragment AlertScreen{31acea7 #2 id=0x7f0d0076}

Comment: I have created a different editor.xml file to put fragment_container. If not such, how and where i should define fragment_container ??

Comment: `R.id.fragment_container` should be the `id` of a container (`ViweGroup`) that holds fragments and should be part of the activity layout.

Comment: How you are adding the first `fragment`?

Comment: This fragment_container should be the part of which layout file ? **activity_main.xml** ?

Comment: yeah and thats why I asked, how are you adding the first `fragment`?

Comment: First fragment is the part of a  tab Layout implemented by View Page and Pager.

Comment: Then its no that easy as any fragment would need a container.

Comment: Could you please provide a code that could work in this scenario. Only the part which concerns fragment_container.

Comment: I generally add/remove fragments from a single container (say `<FrameLayout>`) with a given `id`. Now, since you are using `ViewPager` which might have its own purpose, one on the things you can do is create a new activity and do the above there. I haven't tried this though but you can also try to provide the `id` of the `ViewGroup` your `ViewPager` is a part of in the `replace()` above.